# Incorrect WGS84 to UTM conversion in GeoPandas to_crs and estimate_utm_crs

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, wgs84, utm

Does anyone ever encounter this weird inconsistency in GeoPandas to_crs and estimate_utm_crs:

```
import utm
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

for lon in range(110, 130, 2):
    lat = 25
    x1, y1, *_ = utm.from_latlon(lat, lon)
    gpd_pnt = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(lon, lat)], crs=4326)
    est_utm = gpd_pnt.estimate_utm_crs()
    gpd_pnt_utm = gpd_pnt.to_crs(est_utm)
    x2, y2 = gpd_pnt_utm.x[0], gpd_pnt_utm.y[0]
    error = np.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    print(f'{gpd_pnt.iloc[0]}, {est_utm}, {x1}, {y1}, {x2}, {y2}, {error:.6f}, {error > 1}')
```

will produce:

```
POINT (110 25), epsg:32649, 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, 399086.9733044734, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (112 25), epsg:32649, 600913.0266956311, 2765319.9440200706, 600913.0266955344, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (114 25), epsg:32649, 197181.31218943797, 2768300.2187555684, 802818.6877849245, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (116 25), epsg:32650, 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, 399086.9733044708, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (118 25), epsg:32650, 600913.0266956337, 2765319.9440200706, 600913.0266955318, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (120 25), epsg:32650, 197181.3121894354, 2768300.2187555684, 802818.6877849195, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (122 25), epsg:32651, 399086.97330436634, 2765319.9440200706, 399086.9733044708, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (124 25), epsg:32651, 600913.0266956311, 2765319.9440200706, 600913.0266955318, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (126 25), epsg:32651, 197181.31218943797, 2768300.2187555684, 802818.687784922, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (128 25), epsg:32652, 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, 399086.9733044734, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
```

where the lines end with "True" is the concerning parts.

Is that due to some rounding error?
The weirdness exists periodically on a larger span if you change the range and step of the "lon" for-loop.

Any suggestion will be great

**Update:**

As pointed out by Ian Turton, I revised my test code as shown:

```
for lon in range(110, 130, 2):
    lat = 25
    x1, y1, *z1 = utm.from_latlon(lat, lon)
    gpd_pnt = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(lon, lat)], crs=4326)
    est_utm = gpd_pnt.estimate_utm_crs()
    gpd_pnt_utm = gpd_pnt.to_crs(est_utm)
    x2, y2 = gpd_pnt_utm.x[0], gpd_pnt_utm.y[0]
    error = np.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    print(f'{gpd_pnt.iloc[0]}, {x1}, {y1}, {z1}, {est_utm}, {x2}, {y2}, {error:.6f}, {error > 1}')
```

```
POINT (110 25), 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, [49, 'R'], epsg:32649, 399086.9733044734, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (112 25), 600913.0266956311, 2765319.9440200706, [49, 'R'], epsg:32649, 600913.0266955344, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (114 25), 197181.31218943797, 2768300.2187555684, [50, 'R'], epsg:32649, 802818.6877849245, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (116 25), 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, [50, 'R'], epsg:32650, 399086.9733044708, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (118 25), 600913.0266956337, 2765319.9440200706, [50, 'R'], epsg:32650, 600913.0266955318, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (120 25), 197181.3121894354, 2768300.2187555684, [51, 'R'], epsg:32650, 802818.6877849195, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (122 25), 399086.97330436634, 2765319.9440200706, [51, 'R'], epsg:32651, 399086.9733044708, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (124 25), 600913.0266956311, 2765319.9440200706, [51, 'R'], epsg:32651, 600913.0266955318, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
POINT (126 25), 197181.31218943797, 2768300.2187555684, [52, 'R'], epsg:32651, 802818.687784922, 2768300.2187736086, 605637.375595, True
POINT (128 25), 399086.9733043689, 2765319.9440200706, [52, 'R'], epsg:32652, 399086.9733044734, 2765319.9440362453, 0.000016, False
```

yeah, unsurprisingly, the problem is right in the transition zone. so it's dangerous to mix implementation of UTM conversion I guess?

Comment: Are you going over the edge of the zone or very close to it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the estimated CRS/UTM zone from geopandas is different than the UTM zone that is output from the `utm` module in these cases. If you look at line 3 in your output above the output from the `utm.fromlat()` method produces `[50, 'R']` but the `est_utm` is in UTM zone 49. Take a look [here](https://epsg.io/32649) and you will see the bounds lie right on `lon=114` which is where the first `error>1` evaluates to True. So, coordinates that you are looking at in these `True` cases are in different projections. It's happening every 3rd point because UTM zones are 6 degrees wide and you're stepping through the `range` by 2. `6 / 2 = 3`.

If you build the CRS from the ZONE_NUMBER (what you have in the variable `z1`) then you will see this is resolved. Below is a hacky way to show this using the output in `z1`, but is not a good way to create a CRS.

```
from pyproj import CRS
for lon in range(110, 130, 2):
    lat = 25
    x1, y1, *z1 = utm.from_latlon(lat, lon)
    gpd_pnt = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(lon, lat)], crs=4326)
    est_utm = gpd_pnt.estimate_utm_crs()
    d = est_utm.to_dict()
    if d["zone"] != z1[0]:
        d["zone"] = z1[0] # update to the zone from `utm.fromlatlon()`
        est_utm = CRS.from_dict(d)
    gpd_pnt_utm = gpd_pnt.to_crs(est_utm)
    x2, y2 = gpd_pnt_utm.x[0], gpd_pnt_utm.y[0]
    error = np.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    print(f'{gpd_pnt.iloc[0]}, {error:.6f}, {error > 1}')
```

And the output:

```
POINT (110 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (112 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (114 25), 0.000031, False
POINT (116 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (118 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (120 25), 0.000031, False
POINT (122 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (124 25), 0.000016, False
POINT (126 25), 0.000031, False
POINT (128 25), 0.000016, False
```